# undefined method dbal_mysqli::fetch_array() in phpbb ban script

Tags: php, mysqli, phpbb, phpbb3

Hi guys i trying to make a script for ban users by sending his username via post method.
for needed function i imported needed files via include code in header.

but i have this error :

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method dbal_mysqli::fetch_array() in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpBB3\ban.php on line 25
```

and my code is:

```
<?php

$phpbb_root_path = '../phpbb3/';
define('IN_PHPBB', true);
define('IN_CHECK_BAN', 1);
define('IN_LOGIN', 1);
$phpEx = substr(strrchr(__FILE__, '.'), 1);
include($phpbb_root_path . 'common.' . $phpEx);
include_once($phpbb_root_path . 'includes/functions_profile_fields.' . $phpEx);
if ( !function_exists('group_memberships') )
{
        include_once($phpbb_root_path . 'includes/functions_user.'.$phpEx);
}


if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' )
{
    $username = '';

    $post = file_get_contents( "php://input" );     
    sscanf( $post, "%s", $username);
}

$query = "SELECT user_id, username FROM phpbb_users WHERE username = '" . $db->sql_escape($username) . "'";
$user = $db->fetch_array($query);


$sql = 'SELECT FROM phpbb_banlist WHERE ban_userid = ' . $user['uid'] . '';
if($db->fetch_field($sql, "ban_userid"))    
{
      // $errors[] = "user alredy banned";
}
else
{
    $insert_array = array(
            'ban_userid'        =>  $user['uid'],
            'ban_start'         => (int) $current_time,
            'ban_end'           => (int) $ban_end,
            'ban_exclude'       => (int) $ban_exclude,
            'ban_reason'        => (string) $ban_reason,
            'ban_give_reason'   => (string) $ban_give_reason,
        );

    $db->insert_query('phpbb_banlist', $insert_array);
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing $user = $db->fetch_array to $db->query.

I don't think dbal_mysqli has a fetch_array method. More information here: http://area51.phpbb.com/docs/code/31x/dbal/dbal_mysqli.html#sql_query()

Comment: but i need array to return username and user_id from $query. so you think how i can do this?

Comment: You are using a weird module (dbal_mysqli) that doesn't natively support arrays but its parent class dbal has an array return method called 'sql_fetchrowset' so perhaps try that? If you can, I think the proper library for you would be (dbal_mysql).